# Issues installing Scrapy on windows

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I already have anaconda installed `version 4.5.4`, i went to the cmd to install scrapy referring to the docs `pip install Scrapy` and got the following error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

I tried going to that link but they just give me error 404 page not found.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted to download crossponding whl which may needed when install scrapy.

Then install it: e.g. `pip install C:\Twisted-17.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`, depends on your python version and platform, you may need to download different whl. BTW,cp36 mean cpython3.6.

Finally pip install Scrapy again.

You did not give the full error, and I forgot what others needed. If need others, you can also find it on that web. With this, you can no need to install VC++ and quickly make your environment ready.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the visual c++ build tools. The link in the error message seems like it's dead, but you can download them here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Note that while the error is calling for visual c++ 14.0 - everything will work with newer versions of visual c++.